# Quick Fix: Getting rid of AutoComplete in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, autocomplete

So, it has come to my attention that Google decided to remove functionality for HTML's `autocorrect="off"` so no matter if you use this on your form, or individual element's Google Chrome still show autocompleted data fill.

So, puzzling aroud, I couldn't think of a way how to fix this, and then I figured it out! (see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input has a value, then autocomplete won't over-rule you and put user's data in!

So for instance: `<input type="text" name="username" value=" ">` - Notice the space inbetween **value**?

Now, if you're entering this data into a database, make sure you make use of PHP's own `trim()` function to remove any whitespace! - Or do a `str_replace` on the string!

So, for instance, here is what I have to check if my input exists (OOP, not procedural!)

```
if(!Input::get('username')) {
    $user_name = ' ';
} else { 
    $user_name = escape(Input::get('username'));
}
```

So, you can see, I am checking to see if there is a value in my textbox and if there isn't I am setting the variable `$user_name` to a blank space, and if there is, for my functionality, I will output the username they entered.

**Please Note:** My input after `else {` is wrapped in an escape() function, this is a function I have made to prevent against invalid data/queries being entered into the string to create a SQL injection.

**Procedural code** would look along the lines of this:

```
if(!$_GET['username']) {
    $user_name = ' ';
} else {
    $user_name = $_GET['username'];
}
```

Hope this helps some of you!